How do I dispatch a Compute Shader kernel and know which index of the buffer to access inside the function?
I'm new to Compute Shaders so this may seem trivial, but it's a lot to wrap my head around.
When calling Dispatch on a Compute Shader we seem to be throwing a work problem at the GPU and letting it decide how to distribute the workload. Great, but when that workload is performing an operation that should, say, take indexes from a StructuredBuffer<int> InputIndexes and modify a corresponding RWStructuredBuffer<MyStruct> MyDataSet, how do we know which index to modify when using uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID?
For example, if we decorate the kernel with [numthreads(64,1,1)] then say that the index we want to run is id.x, will that work? What happens if I have more than 64 inputs in the buffer? Will id.x basically be the index I want to modify in this instance of the function being run? If I use a different 3d group shape, how do I determine which index is the target index in the buffer data set?
